Asynchronous work without window freezing
I have a mobile application on kivy, it works well. Until I try to implement asynchronous execution of site parsing in it, so that the main gui kivy window does not hang and I can interact with it during the execution of a long process. Then the second file parsing the site does not work correctly, especially where the wait for js execution is performed. It either does not wait for js to execute, or waits but with an error somewhere in the process of waiting and entering the result, as a result the result is incorrect.
Example of code without asynchronous execution. I repeat. The second script file works fine only in this mode (when it calls a function via asyncio.run(), and inside it new_loop, otherwise it does not work fine with the site on which the js script is executed. (Selenium is not recommended).
I also processed my question in chatgpt - it did not help. Re-failure options:

standard kivymd features (from kivymd.utils.asynckivy import start, sleep)

asyncio (and the entire main.run() in it and purely the load function or only the second script in the call)

threading / concurrent.futures (purely through them and together with asyncio)

asynckivy (which is separately installed) also did not work Nothing helped. The application was able to start working asynchronously, but the result from the second script was then executed/arrived incorrectly.


First script:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.clipboard import Clipboard as Cb
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatIconButton
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
import cheker as checkN

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>
    MDList:
        OneLineIconListItem:
            text: "Home"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"
            IconLeftWidget:
                icon: 'home'
                
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        id: home
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            elevation: 4
            title: "OSINT"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        MDNavigationLayout:
            id: navig
            MDScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                MDScreen:
                    id: scr_1
                    name: "scr 1"
                    MDBottomNavigation:
                        id: sc_0
                        selected_color_background: "orange"
                        text_color_active: "lightgrey"
                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            id: sc_1
                            name: 'screen 1'
                            text: 'Home'
                            icon: 'home'
                            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                                id: lst1
                                text: 'Choose option'
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.7}
                                on_release: app.menu.open()
                            MDTextField:
                                id: txt
                                hint_text: ''
                                helper_text: ''
                                helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
                                text: ''
                                mode: 'rectangle'
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.45}
                                size_hint: 0.28, 0.15
                            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                                id: startbutton
                                text: 'Start'
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.20}
                                on_release: app.start()
                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            id: sc_3
                            name: 'screen 3'
                            text: 'Result'
                            icon: 'text'
                            ScrollView:
                                MDLabel:
                                    id: scroll
                                    markup: True
                                    text: ''
                                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                                    font_size: '15sp'
                                    multiline: True
                                    text_size: self.width, None
                                    size_hint_y: None
                                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                                    on_touch_down: app.linki(app.bufftext)
                                    on_ref_press: app.webopen(args[1])
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager
                    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.list_info = ['Number']
        self.dl = Window.width
        self.sh = Window.height

        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

        menu_items = [
            {
                'id': 'm1',
                'text': f'{i}',
                'viewclass': 'OneLineListItem',
                'on_release': lambda x=f'{i}': self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in self.list_info
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.lst1,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=5,
        )

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        self.screen.ids.lst1.text = text_item
        self.screen.ids.txt.hint_text = text_item
        lst2 = self.screen.ids.sc_1
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = 'M3'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.title = 'OSINT'
        return self.screen

    def start(self):
        self.screen.ids.sc_0.switch_tab('screen 3')
        self.root.ids.scroll.text = f'Please wait'
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.load(), 1.0)

    def load(self):
        self.res = ''

        opt1 = self.screen.ids.lst1.text
        opt3 = self.screen.ids.txt.text

        if opt1 != 'Choose option':
            if opt1 == 'Number':
                self.res = checkN.parse_num(opt3)
        else:
            self.root.ids.scroll.text = 'Select/enter the correct data.'

        if self.res != '':
            self.root.ids.scroll.text = self.res
        else:
            self.root.ids.scroll.text = 'No results'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()

Second script:

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from fake_useragent import UserAgent

import asyncio

from requests_html import HTMLSession, AsyncHTMLSession



def parse_num(numbers):

    try:

        res1 = europe(numbers)

    except:

        res1 = f'{color.RED}[info]:{color.END}\nError internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n'



    try:

        res2 = asyncio.run(all_num(numbers))

    except:

        res2 = f'{color.RED}[whosenumber.info]:{color.END}\nError internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n'

        

    try:

        res4 = europe(numbers)

    except:

        res4 = f'{color.RED}[ua.tellows.org]:{color.END}\nError internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n'



    res = res1+res2+res4

    return res



async def all_num(numbers):

    uu='https://whosenumber.info'

    headers = {'User-Agent': f'{UserAgent().random}', }

    url = f'{uu}/'

    new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)

    session = AsyncHTMLSession()



    response = session.get(f'{url}{numbers}', headers=headers, timeout=60)



    await response.html.arender(sleep=10)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, 'html.parser')

    try:

        divF_tag = soup.find('div', attrs={'style':'padding:10px; padding-left:20px;'})

        ttl = ''

        try:

            divS_tag = divF_tag.find('span', attrs={'id':'t_reiting'})

            ttl = divS_tag.get_text()

        except:

            pass

        comm = ''

        try:

            ij = 1

            for p_tag in divF_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'style': 'margin-left:15px;margin-top:10px;color:#6a6a6a; padding-bottom:10px;'}):

                try:

                    pp_tag = p_tag.get_text()

                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<br/>', '')

                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<br>', '')

                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<b/>', '')

                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<b>', '')

                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('</b>', '')

                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('</br>', '')

                    comm += f'    [{ij}]: {pp_tag}\n'

                    ij+=1

                except:

                    continue

        except:

            pass

        logger.info('all - there is a result')

        resF = (f'{color.RED}[whosenumber.info] - info:{color.END}\n'

                f'{color.BOLD}Rating: {color.END}{ttl}\n{color.BOLD}Comments: {color.END}\n{comm}\n')

    except:

        logger.info('all - result error')

        resF = (f'{color.RED}[whosenumber.info] - info:{color.END}\n'

                f'Error internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n')



    res = f'\n{resF}'

    await session.close()

    new_loop.close()

    return res



def europe(numbers):

    uu = 'https://ua.tellows.org'

    headers = {'User-Agent': f'{UserAgent().random}', }

    url = f'{uu}/num/'



    response = requests.get(f'{url}{numbers}', headers=headers, timeout=60)



    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    try:

        ttl = ""

        comm = ""

        for divF_tag in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'userratings'}):

            try:

                for divS_tag in divF_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'col-md-4 mt-2'}):

                    try:

                        for h5_tag in divS_tag.findAll('h5'):

                            ttl += f"{color.BOLD}{h5_tag.get_text()}{color.END}\n"

                        for th_tag in divS_tag.findAll('th'):

                            tt = str(th_tag).replace("<th>\n                    ", "")

                            tt = tt.replace("                        ", "")

                            tt = tt.replace('<br/>\n<span class="small">', ": ")

                            tt = tt.replace("</span>\n</th>", "")

                            ttl += f"    {tt}\n"

                    except:

                        continue

            except:

                continue

        for comms_tag in soup.findAll('ol', attrs={'id': 'singlecomments'}):

            try:

                ii = 1

                comm += f"{color.BOLD}Comments: {color.END}\n"

                for comm_tag in comms_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'col comment-body'}):

                    try:

                        for pCom_tag in comm_tag.findAll('p', attrs={'class': 'mb-0'}):

                            comm += f"    [{ii}]{pCom_tag.get_text()}\n"

                            ii += 1

                    except:

                        continue

                    try:

                        jj = 1

                        for dCom_tag in comm_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'ccomment'}):

                            try:

                                comm += f"        [0{jj}]{dCom_tag.get_text()}\n"

                                jj += 1

                            except:

                                continue

                    except:

                        continue

            except:

                continue

        logger.info('Europe - there is a result')

        resF = (f'{color.RED}[ua.tellows.org] - info:{color.END}\n'

                f'{ttl}\n{comm}\n')

    except:

        logger.info('Europe - result error')

        resF = (f'{color.RED}[ua.tellows.org] - info:{color.END}\n'

                f'{color.BOLD}Info: {color.END}Error internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n')

    res = f'\n{resF}'

    response.close()

    return res



Please test the source code I provided and try to add asynchronous execution of kivy to it, so that the gui window does not freeze, but at the same time the second script is executed normally (the result comes from parsing the site), especially in the function where the expectation of the site js execution is executed. For the test, the number that needs to be entered in the application: +37129502847. I took it from the tested site to get the exact result.
